# MongoDB aggregate and transform subset of data based on array of values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given this sample data:

```
[   
    {
      "_id": "5798ae78670bc85f3e3fe0df",
      "defines": [
            {
              "domain": "ism:SecurityLabel",
              "name": "access",
              "@id": "ntk:access"
            },
            {
              "domain": "ntk:AccessProfileType",
              "name": "profileDes",
              "@id": "ntk:profileDes"
            },
            {
              "domain": "ntk:AccessType",
              "name": "requiresAllOf",
              "@id": "ntk:requiresAllOf"
            },

            {
              "domain": "ism:SecurityLabel",
              "name": "bannerMark",
              "@id": "ism:bannerMark"
            },
            {
              "label": "Need-to-Know Access Profile Type",
              "name": "AccessProfileType",
              "@id": "ntk:AccessProfileType"
            },
            {
              "label": "Need-to-Know Access Type"
              "name": "AccessType",
              "@id": "ntk:AccessType"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5798ae78670bc85f3e3fe0e1",
        "defines": [        
            {
              "domain": "ntk:AccessProfileType",
              "name": "accessPolicy",
              "@id": "ntk:accessPolicy"
            },
            {
              "domain": "ism:SecurityLabel",
              "name": "atomicEnergyMarking",
              "@id": "ism:atomicEnergyMarking"
            },
            {
              "domain": "ism:SecurityLabel",
              "name": "classification",
              "@id": "ism:classification"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to query the collection where `defines.domain $in ["ism:SecurityLabel", "ntk:AccessProfileType"]` and return an object with each domain having an array of its matched defines, like this:

```
{   

    "ism:SecurityLabel": [
        {
            "domain": "ism:SecurityLabel",
            "name": "access"
            "@id": "ntk:access"
        },
        {
            "domain": "ism:SecurityLabel",
            "name": "bannerMark"
            "@id": "ism:bannerMark"
        },
        {
            "domain": "ism:SecurityLabel",
            "name": "atomicEnergyMarking",
            "@id": "ism:atomicEnergyMarking"
        },
        {
            "domain": "ism:SecurityLabel",
            "name": "classification",
            "@id": "ism:classification"
        }
    ],
    "ntk:AccessProfileType": [
        {
            "domain": "ntk:AccessProfileType",
            "name": "profileDes"
            "@id": "ntk:profileDes"
        },
        {
            "domain": "ntk:AccessProfileType",
            "name": "accessPolicy"
            "@id": "ntk:accessPolicy"
        }       
    ]
}
```

I've attempted to match and then project my  results but I really have no clue how I would transform the data from the format it's in to the format I need.

```
{ 
    $match: {
        'defines.domain': { $in: types } 
    } 
},
{
    $project: {
        defines: {
            $filter: {
                // ??? not sure what to do ???
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this query. This is not exactly as you have asked but i think nearer. Also, when you are posting a question. please make sure your test data is good. you were missing some comma's in it.

```
db.testing.aggregate([ 
    { $match: {'defines.domain': { $in: ["ism:SecurityLabel", "ntk:AccessProfileType"] } } },
    {$unwind:"$defines"},
    {$match:{"defines.domain":{$in:["ism:SecurityLabel", "ntk:AccessProfileType"]}}},
    {$group:{"_id":"$defines.domain",data:{$push:"$defines"}}}
]).pretty()
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the sample data.